# How Can I Run/Execute Databricks notebook from azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks, cicd

I was able to deploy my Artifact(notebook) into Databrick Workspace successfully. But how can I run that Notebook directly from Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Suggest any ways I can achieve this?

Comment: you just want to run notebook, or you want to execute tests?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Alex. I Want to run my deployed notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Devops has Run Notebook task which you can configure.

Or you can use this template too. Create a new `azure_pipelines.yaml`, and confgure the required variables:

```
resources:
  - repo: self

trigger:
  - master

variables:
  databricks-host: 'https://${databricksRegion}.azuredatabricks.net'
  notebook-folder: '/Shared/tmp/'
  cluster-id: '1234-567890-bobby123'
  notebook-name: 'tests'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.x'

- script: |
    pip install databricks-cli
  displayName: 'Install databricks-cli'

- script: |
   databricks fs cp mnt/demo/ dbfs:/tmp/demo --recursive --overwrite

   databricks workspace import_dir src/ $(notebook-folder) -o

   JOB_ID=$(databricks jobs create --json '{
     "name": "Testrun",
     "existing_cluster_id": "$(cluster-id)",
     "timeout_seconds": 3600,
     "max_retries": 1,
     "notebook_task": {
       "notebook_path": "$(notebook-folder)$(notebook-name)",
       "base_parameters": {}
     }
   }' | jq '.job_id')

   RUN_ID=$(databricks jobs run-now --job-id $JOB_ID | jq '.run_id')

   job_status="PENDING"
   while [ $job_status = "RUNNING" ] || [ $job_status = "PENDING" ]
   do
     sleep 2
     job_status=$(databricks runs get --run-id $RUN_ID | jq -r '.state.life_cycle_state')
     echo Status $job_status
   done

   RESULT=$(databricks runs get-output --run-id $RUN_ID)

   RESULT_STATE=$(echo $RESULT | jq -r '.metadata.state.result_state')
   RESULT_MESSAGE=$(echo $RESULT | jq -r '.metadata.state.state_message')
   if [ $RESULT_STATE = "FAILED" ]
   then
     echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]$RESULT_MESSAGE"
     echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]$RESULT_MESSAGE"
   fi

   echo $RESULT | jq .
  displayName: 'Run Databricks Notebook'
  env:
    DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(databricks-token)
    DATABRICKS_HOST: $(databricks-host)
```

Comment: Thanks @partha_devArch. In databricks notebook my code is in Scala language can I use above YAML to run notebook. Please suggest.

Comment: yes sure, have you tried it?